# Getting calendar's owner email address of an AppointmentItem

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In to send all the appointments to a web app and I'm having some trouble consistently getting the "owner" (not the organizer) of an AppointmentItem.

For example, X sends an appointment to Y and Z.
The Add-In will get three appointment items out of it, I'm trying to get the email address of X, Y and Z.

I tried to look into the SendUsingAccount (sometimes set to null) or the Parent property but I can't seem to find what I'm looking for.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you mean the owner of the mailbox where the appointment is residing? Or the organizer of the appointment?

Comment: Hello Dmitry, I mean the owner of the mailbox where the appointment is residing.

Comment: Does the appointment come form the default mailbox, a delegate mailbox added to the profile, or a shared Calendar folder opened through File | Open | Other User's folder?

Comment: It's from the default mailbox if I'm not wrong. I have a profile with multiple accounts to it and I tried to create an appointment (from one of the profile's account) and invite the other accounts, and I'm trying to get the email address for each of these accounts' AppointmentItem related to the previously created appointment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is the default account and assuming there is only one primary Exchange account configured in Outlook, you can simply use `Application.Session.CurrentUser`.

**UPDATE**:
If you are accessing an appointment from a non-default Exchange account, you can retrieve the parent `Store` - you can do that through `AppointmentItem.Parent` (it will be `MAPIFolder`), then use `MAPIFolder.Store` or `StoreID` property. You can then match the store to an `Account` object from the `Namespace.Accounts` collection using `Account.DeliveryStore`. Compare the two store entry ids using `Namespace.CompareEntryIDs`, don't compare the strings directly.
Once you can the Account object, you can use Account.CurrentUser property.

If using [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) is an option (I am its author), it exposes [RDOExchangeMailboxStore](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#RDOExchangeMailboxStore).`Owner` property so that you don't have to go through the accounts: just create [RDOSession](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdosession.htm) object, set its `MAPIOBJECT` property to `Application.Session.MAPIOBJECT` from Outlook, reopen the appointment appointment using `RDOSession.GetMessageFromID` or `GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject`, and use [RDOAppointmentItem](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAppointmenItem.htm).`Parent.Store.Owner`.

Comment: I misunderstood, for each of these accounts I need their email address, not the email address of the primary account, so if there are four accounts involved, I'll have four different emails. I was thinking about using AppointmentItem.Parent.Parent.Name, it seems that it's what I'm looking for but I'm not sure if it will always be an email address.

Comment: That's why I asked where the appointment resides. What exactly do you mean by "four accounts involved"?  Again, is that the default mailbox, a delegate mailbox added to the profile, or a shared Calendar folder opened through File | Open | Other User's folder?

Comment: I mean I have a profile with four accounts in it. I made a test where one of these accounts invited the other three to an appointment. In my program, I made a loop where I recover all the appointment items (so I'm getting four AppointmentItem objects, one for each of these accounts, but all these AppointmentItem are related to the same appointment I just created) and I'm trying to get the email address linked to each of these accounts (so four different values). By using CurrentUser, I'd get the same user four times. I don't think it's a shared calendar, there's no delegation either.

Comment: Thanks for the update Dmitry, that's exactly what I needed.