# Getting an Internet calendar's owner email address from an AppointmentItem in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I'm developing an Outlook Add-In in which I am trying to get a Calendar's Onwer Email Id in the Calenders ItemAdd Event. I had tried the method in the below post and it works for default accounts, but its not working when the Calendar is an Internet Calender Subscription.

[Getting calendar's owner email address of an AppointmentItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631333/getting-calendars-owner-email-address-of-an-appointmentitem)

The `AppointmentItem.Parent` StoreID is not matching any `Account` Object in case of Internet Calendar. Is there any other way using which I can get the Calendar Owners email Address?

Thanks for your help!

I am using below code

```
GetCalendarOwner(Outlook.AppointmentItem appointment)
        {

            Outlook.MAPIFolder folder = appointment.Parent;
            string email = "";

            foreach (Outlook.Account account in Application.Session.Accounts)
            {
                Outlook.MAPIFolder folder2 = account.DeliveryStore.GetDefaultFolder(Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderCalendar);

                if (Application.Session.CompareEntryIDs(folder.Store.StoreID, account.DeliveryStore.StoreID))
                {
                    Outlook.AddressEntry accountEmail = account.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
                    if (accountEmail != null)
                    {
                        if (accountEmail.AddressEntryUserType ==
                            Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry ||
                            accountEmail.AddressEntryUserType ==
                            Outlook.OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry)
                        {
                            Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = accountEmail.GetExchangeUser();
                            if (exchUser != null)
                            {
                                email = exchUser.PrimarySmtpAddress;
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            email = account.SmtpAddress;
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
                            {
                                email = accountEmail.Address;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            return email;
        }
```

Comment: What code exactly do you use?

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I have put the code which I am using.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what code exactly is used in the `ItemSend` event handler. Anyway, it seems you are interested in the [MeetingItem.SendUsingAccount](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.meetingitem.sendusingaccount) property that returns or sets an `Account` object that represents the account to use to send the `MeetingItem`.

You can use the SendUsingAccount property to specify the account that the Send method uses to send the MeetingItem. This property returns Null (Nothing in Visual Basic) if the account specified for the MeetingItem no longer exists or the default/primary one is used (see `Namespace.CurrentUser`).

Comment: I am using this code from ```ItemAdd``` event handler. I have a profile with multiple accounts and I want to know who is the Calendar Owner when a Meeting Item is added in the Calendar.