# C# Outlook Add-In > Appointment Owner > Retrieve Active Directory Account

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

In an Outlook Add-In, I want from an appointment to retrieve the corresponding AD account. The Outlook client can potentially have multiple calendars from different shared accounts.
I produced the below code but is unsure about the following:

1. Are the references used the right ones to link the Appointment Owner -> The Outlook account -> The AD account
2. How to retrieve the AD account corresponding to the Outlook Account

I manage to extract the username and SMTP address but is unsure if I can search in the AD based on those?
I reviewed: [Getting calendar's owner email address of an AppointmentItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57631333/getting-calendars-owner-email-address-of-an-appointmentitem)

````
```C#
var currentAppointmentUserID = appointmentItem.Parent.Parent.Parent.Currentuser.EntryID;
// Outlook application.
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
// Loop through Accounts
Account currentAppointmentAccount = null;
foreach(Account acc in oApp.Session.Accounts) 
  {
  if (acc.CurrentUser.EntryID == currentAppointmentUserID) 
  {
    currentAppointmentAccount = acc;
    break;
  }
}
if (currentAppointmentAccount != null) {
  Logger.WriteLine(LogLevel.Debug, "Exchange account found: " + currentAppointmentAccount.UserName + " -> SMTP Address: " + currentAppointmentAccount.SmtpAddress);

  // Query AD for account with SMTP address
  using(PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "MyDomain")) 
    {
    UserPrincipal userFound = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, EmailAddress);

    if (userFound != null) 
    {
      userFound.FirstName = yourUser.GivenName;
      userFound.LastName = yourUser.Surname;
    }
  }
}
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, if anyone is interested:

```
string PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x661B0102";

try {
   Store store = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetStoreFromID(appointmentItem.Parent.StoreID);
   string mailOwnerEntryId = store.PropertyAccessor.BinaryToString(store.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_MAILBOX_OWNER_ENTRYID));
   AddressEntry addr = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetAddressEntryFromID(mailOwnerEntryId);

   if (addr.Type == "EX") {
      ExchangeUser exUser = appointmentItem.GetOrganizer().GetExchangeUser();
      Console.WriteLine("The SamAccountName is: " + exUser.Alias);
   } else {
      Console.WriteLine("Address is not of Exchange type.");
      }
   } catch (System.Exception ex) {}
```

Comment: How you get obj appointmentItem.Parent? ``AppointmentItem appointmentItem = new AppointmentItem();  ExchangeUser exUser = appointmentItem.GetOrganizer().GetExchangeUser();``

Comment: Hello Eden, sorry, I am not sure to understand the question. You can retrieve the appointment partent by using the corresponding function appointmentItem.Parent

Comment: ``Store store = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Session.GetStoreFromID(appointmentItem.Parent.StoreID);``  , who is appointmentItem?How you find him?

Comment: Well it depends on your business logic. In my case sometimes I am creating a new appointment:
AppointmentItem newAppointment = (AppointmentItem)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CreateItem(OlItemType.olAppointmentItem);
And others situation I am using the existing appointement retrieve from the inspector: 
Item = (Outlook.AppointmentItem)Inspector.CurrentItem;
You can use this reference to start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-your-first-vsto-add-in-for-outlook?view=vs-2022